# date add command Terminal: How to add time using `date`? (illegal time format)

Tags: macos, high-sierra, command-line

I'm trying to add minutes to the current time using `date`. This works for adding 5 minutes:

```
$ date -v "+5M"
```

But if I try using `-v` with a formatting argument, it fails and prints the help menu:

```
$ date "+%r" -v "+5M"
date: illegal time format
```

Is it possible to use the `%r` formatting with `-v`?

Answer (score 4):

Put `"+%r"` after the `"+5M"`:

```
$ date -v "+5M" "+%r"
02:25:14 PM
```